# How do I restrict my chrome app from being opened multiple times (so just one instance)?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome app that I need to be just one instance. If they click the app icon again, it should go to the already opened instance instead of opening another instance. How would I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the window with an `id` and as a `singleton`. See the [chrome.app.window](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html) documentation.

E.G. modify the [hello world](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/hello-world/main.js) sample to create the window with

```
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: "", // Even an empty string is sufficient.
    singleton: true,
```

Comment: Is this better than doing it the way Chrome's example singleton app does it (which I just found)? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/singleton/main.js How would I focus the already open window?

Comment: Yes this is a better way of doing it as it is more automatic. The singleton sample should be updated to reflect this way of doing it, which was added after the sample was created. Calling create with an ID of an existing window will focus the existing window for you.

Comment: It appears the "id" is meant to be an app-internal identifier of the window. SO it's not the appId, but an id for that window within the application itself (or the application's `chrome.runtime` instance).

Comment: `id:` works like and iFrame id, to identify "windows". It's independent of the `appID`